# Importing data using SSIS using a Web Service (https) as destination

Tags: ssl, https, ssis, etl

Trying to set up a data import from SQL Server to the cloud (destination Web Service Task), only the destination requires a SSL certificate (https).

[image]

is there a way to natively bypass this SSL security check using the Web Service Task? (i.e. without installing 3rd party tools)

Comment: Also having issues connecting to a web service endpoint over https in ssis.  In my case it's throwing HRESULT 0xC0016004 , may be equivalent to your error.